# Iphone http streaming video problem

Tags: iphone, http, streaming

When our application play new url of http streaming video , mpmovieplayer show previous image of video during loading new video from new url .
In detail , it show last part of previous video then show first part of previous that video again ( all captured image ) then it plays new url http streaming . 
We need your advice  how to solve this . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in the MPMoviePlayerController.  You can work around it by adding the following to your `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` callback:

```
[myMoviePlayerController stop];
[myMoviePlayerController setInitialPlaybackTime: -1.0];
```